# Remove pairs of Ints from a list of lists, while keeping the original order - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have been struggling to remove duplicates from a list of list, while keeping the original position of the remainders and empty lists. Let's say:

```
list1 = [[1],[2],[1,2],[4],[1,4]]
list2 =[[1],[2],[1,2],[4],[1,4],[2,4]]
list3 = [[1,2,4],[1,4],[2,4],[1,4],[1,2,4]]
```

Then the output should be:

```
[[],[],[],[],[1]]

[[],[],[],[],[1],[2,4]]

[[],[],[,],[],[2,4]]
```

(which pairs get removed is not important)

However, I can only get this to work if i first flatten the list, but then i lose the original position of the empty lists. If anyone has any idea how I can go about solving this I would be gratefull!

The code is messy, but works for flat list:

```
remPair [] = []
remPair (x:xs) = if elem x xs then
                    let
                      n = elemIndices x xs
                      (ys, zs) = splitAt (head n) xs
                      in remPair (ys ++ (drop 1 zs))
                  else  [x] ++ remPair xs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Correct Response

I tried to solve it in a Haskell-y way, but this code has horrible performance and is hard to read. I just wanted to see if I could solve the problem.

```hs
import Data.List (elemIndices)

appendHead :: a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
appendHead x [] = [[x]]
appendHead x (ys:yss) = (x:ys):yss

-- | count how many time an element occurs in a list of lists
count :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> Int
count _ [] = 0
count x (ys:yss) = (length $ elemIndices x ys) + count x yss

-- | assume count is 1 or greater for simplicity
rmAllButLast :: Int -> Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
rmAllButLast x xCount yss =  
  if xCount == 0
  then yss
  else
    let protectLastElement cond = if even xCount then cond else True in
    snd $
    foldl
    (\(xIndex,acc) ys ->
        (\y -> acc++[y]) <$> foldl
        (\(xIndex,acc) y ->
           if protectLastElement (xIndex < xCount-1) && x == y
           then (xIndex+1, acc)
             else (xIndex, acc++[y]))
        (xIndex, [])
        ys
    )
    (0, [])
    yss

rmPairs :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
rmPairs [] = []
rmPairs ([]:yss) = [] : rmPairs yss
rmPairs ((x:xs):yss) =
  let xCount = count x (xs:yss) in
  if xCount == 0
  then appendHead x $ rmPairs (xs:yss)
  else rmPairs $ rmAllButLast x xCount (xs:yss)
```

### Old Response

Edit: the code below is not what the author wanted, but I will leave it so the comment below makes sense.

I am not 100% if you want to remove duplicates (anything that occurs once or more would be reduced to one value) or actual pairs (there is two of this value so remove both of them, if there is an even number of x, then they will all be removed, if it is odd value of x then there will be one). Assuming the former and  with no consideration for performance:

```hs
remPair :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
remPair []       = []
remPair ([]:yss) = [] : remPair yss
remPair (xs:yss) = remPairFromFlat xs : remPair yss
  where
    flatYss = concat yss
    remPairFromFlat []     = []
    remPairFromFlat (z:zs) =
      let flat = zs ++ flatYss in
      if z `elem` flat
      then remPairFromFlat zs
      else z : remPairFromFlat zs
```

`remPair` iterates over the list of lists. If the first list is not empty, it flattens out the rest of the list then iterates through the elements of `xs` and creates a local flat list of `ys` and the tail of `xs`.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, but I did indeed want to remove pairs. I will update the examples in the question :) What I ended up doing was converting to binary and then maping XOR to the transposed list. This ended up working for what I needed it for, but I am still lost as to how I can do this more generally. So i will keep the question open, in hopes that someone knows :)

Comment: I think I have figured it out though I am curious if the code is legible.

Comment: Yes this works! I think I get what your functions do, altough I am not well-versed in haskell so the finer details might be lost to me :)  It seems like you solved my main problem when trying to figure out this problem, which was how to keep track of what sub-list have and have not been checked for elem x, and then removing that element from the right index of that sublist. My code quickly turned into an  unreadable mess! Your logic seems a lot more readable to me. Thank you!